# jQuery Script for Hiding DIVs Doesn't Work When Simple Function Call is Added

Tags: jquery

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fyr3b/13/

I have a jQuery script that hides certain parts of the form (in DIVs) depending on which radio button is selected.  It is a basic form where the user inputs quantity, price, and the values are multiplied together whenever any of the values are changed and updates the total value automatically on the page.  The problem arises when I want to simply call a function called "updateFields()" every time a radio button is selected.  Essentially updateFields will update all the totals throughout the form.  Originally my code didn't have the "updateFields();" line (there are a total of 2 calls to it seen below) and it worked great.  However, after adding in the updateFields(); function calls, the code no longer works.  I already tested the updateFields() function alone and it works fine on its own.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

The following code has been updated based on the answers I've received so far.  However I am still experiencing the same symptoms.  Thanks everyone!

This is the code for the hiding and showing parts of the form:

```
$(function() {
$('div.hdp').hide(); // Hide all
showCheckbox(); 

$('input.hdppv').click(function() { // When clicked
    $('div.hdp').hide(); // Hide all
    showCheckbox(); 
});
});

var showCheckbox = function(){ 
$('input.hdppv:checked').each(function() { // Show for checked option
    if($(this).val() == 1)
        $('#hdp_1').show();
    else if($(this).val() == 2)
    {
        $('#hdp_1').show();
        $('#hdp_2').show();
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 3)
    {
        $('#hdp_1').show();
        $('#hdp_2').show();
        $('#hdp_3').show();
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 4)
    {
        $('#hdp_1').show();
        $('#hdp_2').show();
        $('#hdp_3').show();
        $('#hdp_4').show();
    }
});
updateFields();
};
```

Here is the code for updateFields()

```
var updateFields = function() {
var totals = 0;
var quantity1 = $('#quantity1').val();
var quantity2 = $('#quantity2').val();
var quantity3 = $('#quantity3').val();
var quantity4 = $('#quantity4').val();
var price1 = parseFloat($('#price1').val()).toFixed(2);
var price2 = parseFloat($('#price2').val()).toFixed(2);
var price3 = parseFloat($('#price3').val()).toFixed(2);
var price4 = parseFloat($('#price4').val()).toFixed(2);


var type_checked = $('[name="num_products"]:checked').val();
if(type_checked > 0)
{
    totals += parseFloat(quantity1)*parseFloat(price1);
}
if(type_checked > 1)
{
    totals += parseFloat(quantity2)*parseFloat(price2);
}
if(type_checked > 2)
{
    totals += parseFloat(quantity3)*parseFloat(price3);
}
if(type_checked > 3)
{
    totals += parseFloat(quantity4)*parseFloat(price4);
}

if(isNaN(totals))
    var total = 'ERR';

$('#total_box').text('$'+totals); //Change value in text box to the appropriate total       
}
```

UPDATE1::
I suppose I can elaborate a little on what kind of page this is.  This is a form that will allow the user to change the quantity and price of up to 4 items.  At the top of the page there are 4 radio buttons labeled 1 through 4.  If the user checks "1", then the form will only display the first div, which is 2 text boxes for quantity and price.  Upon changing the values in either text boxes, there is a total value that will be displayed at the bottom of the form.  So for example if the user checks "1" then fills in 2 for the quantity and 5 for the price, then the total at the bottom would show $10.  If the user checks "3" then divs 1 through 3 of the form would show, allowing them to put in 3 different quantities and prices, and changing values in those would change the total at the bottom of the page.

What I'm trying to go for is for example if a user chose "3", filled in 2 and 5 respectively in all boxes, then the total should show $30.  However, if they chose to select "1" after doing that, the total should update to $10 as soon as they check "1".  This is what updateFields() does.  The function simply checks to see which radio button is checked (1 through  4) then calculates the total accordingly.

UPDATE2::I took your suggestions and moved updateFields(); to run outside of the .each() function.  Thanks.  Still have the same problem though.  It seems as soon as I place updateFields(); anywhere in that function the form no longer updates even if the user makes any keypresses while in a textbox.  However if I remove it updateFields() runs fine. (I have it running everytime someone presses a key to type in the textboxes as well).

Comment: Don't think it's possible to tell from this sample. Should all work in theory. Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: As Captain John says, it's hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish with this small code sample (especially without knowing what updateFields() contains), but you could factorize it a bit and use switch condition instead of multiple if/else. Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/Akaryatrh/K4kN5/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fyr3b/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what I suggest is, create a function and avoid writing the same code twice, something like this,

```
$(function() {
  $('div.hdp').hide(); // Hide all
      showCheckbox(); 
      updateFields();
  });

  $('input.hdppv').click(function() { // When clicked
        $('div.hdp').hide(); // Hide all
        showCheckbox();
        updateFields();
  });
});

 var showCheckbox = function(){ 
    $('input.hdppv:checked').each(function() { // Show for checked option
       if($(this).val() == 1)
            $('#hdp_1').show();
        else if($(this).val() == 2)
        {
            $('#hdp_1').show();
            $('#hdp_2').show();
        }
        else if($(this).val() == 3)
        {
            $('#hdp_1').show();
            $('#hdp_2').show();
            $('#hdp_3').show();
        }
        else if($(this).val() == 4)
        {
            $('#hdp_1').show();
            $('#hdp_2').show();
            $('#hdp_3').show();
            $('#hdp_4').show();
        }
    });
  };
```

And put the `updateFields();` outside the `each()` function, I don't think it belongs there.

**FINAL EDIT** :

The function definitions of `showCheckbox()` & `updateFields()` needs to be written before calling them, take a look at the code now,

http://jsfiddle.net/fyr3b/25/

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: Well, the question is not complete, and I tried my best to help! I also think that placing the `updateFields()` function outside the `each()` might fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks Rao, I took your suggestion and tidied up  the code a little.  However the code still doesn't work unless I comment out both updateFields() lines.

Comment: set-up your code on jsfiddle.net, It will be a lot easier to debug the code.

Comment: Thanks Rao.  Looking it over.  Noticed I made some typos so here's what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/jJa3S/4/

It looks like the hiding and showing part works, but the total doesn't update when I change the radio selection.

Comment: @JamesGawron This now answers the question. :)

Comment: @user3130810 I have completely fixed the code, take a look! http://jsfiddle.net/fyr3b/25/

Comment: Thank you, Rao.  What's weird is this works great, but when I translate it over to my more complex page it doesn't work again.  I'm probably missing something somewhere, but this helps greatly.  Thank you!!

Comment: I observed that you were using different names, `name="part4_no_num_type"` in html, and `name="num_products"` in js. Also, ids, `id="qty2"` in html and `#quantity1` in js. Try matching identifiers like name, id etc., between your html & js code, also if you have same id for more than one elements, it will not work.

Comment: yes, I was aware of that.  On the actual page i'm working on I was using part4_no_num_type and it matches up everywhere.  I meant to change it to num_products only for this particular post I made. :)

Answer (score 0):

When your page loads, `$('input.hdppv:checked').each()` will run `updateFields()` once for every checked radio button. Is this your desired behavior?

Without seeing whats going on in `updateFields()`, could it be that you just have to add it after all the fields are visible?

```
$('input.hdppv:checked').each(function() {
    ...
}
updateFields();
```

**Edit**

Second request, to have `updateFields()` run whenever a radio button is checked:

```
$('input.hdppv').change(function() {
    updateFields();
});
```

Comment: I elaborated on what updateFields does and how the form works.  My desired behavior is for it to update the total as soon as the form loads, in case there were preloaded values in it already.  In addition I would like updateFields to run whenever any of the radio buttons are checked.

Comment: Updated my answer with functionality to run `updateFields()` when you check a radio button. My first suggestion should still apply. Probably no need to run `updateFields()` multiple times for each radio button upon page load.